# Open multiple virtual hosts by local IP address

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, osx-lion, mamp

I'm using Apache, PHP (MAMP) in OSX environment, and Symfony framework for develpment.
Symfony requires the use of Virtual Host for development locally, so I've added these lines on my `/etc/apache2/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   frontenda.dev
127.0.0.1   frontendb.dev
```

Then at my `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd.vhosts.conf`, I've added these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName frontenda.dev
  DocumentRoot /Users/geo/Sites/frontenda/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName frontendb.dev
  DocumentRoot /Users/geo/Sites/frontendb/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

I can open those folders from my browser by these urls `http://frontenda.dev` or `http://frontendb.dev`. My question is what should I do (if this is even possible) to use IP address instead of `frontenda.dev` or `frontendb.dev`? What I mean with that is, let say my machine ip `192.168.1.144`, can I do `192.168.1.144/frontenda` or even assigning different port number for different folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a better answer. I get it working using xip.io from 37signals http://xip.io/. You can do like this:

```
        10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
    www.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
 mysite.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
foo.bar.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alias to map different paths to different directories

```
Alias /frontenda /Users/geo/Sites/frontenda/www

Alias /frontendb /Users/geo/Sites/frontendb/www
```

Comment: I don't want to use Alias tho.. I want to open that page from my browser using IP..

Comment: That's  exactly what I've shown you how to do. This Alias configuration goes into your Apache .conf file.

Comment: Ok..can you lease be more specific? Where do I type that line of code? And how do I open it in the browser?

Comment: Replace your virtual hosts configuration with the lines that I've given. Access it as you have described in your question.

Comment: Can you please give clear example? I don't know much about server stuffs. Please give me clear example how the code should be. Thanks